# Redirecting input from txt file and storing it in a dynamically created array and comapring it

Tags: c

I am new to C and I am posting here today to get some insight as to how to fix my syntax of my already written code so that it can successfully compare argv and my already created array. Here is my code that I have worked on, but won't compile because of the comparing statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c = 0;
    int *array;
    char *chant;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        array[0]=c;

    }
    chant = strstr(argv[1], array[0]); \\ That is my problem, won't compile here.
    if(chant==NULL)
    printf("false\n");
    else
    printf("true\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's what I want my output to look like when ran:

./a.out paul < beatles.txt

true

Basically, the argv[1] will contain the string paul and then when I direct a text file of the beatles with the name paul in it, my **while loop** will store each character into the array. From there I want my strstr to work, which then results in the program going to the else statement and printing true.

Sorry, but my limited knowledge of C is to blame here and i know that the comparison between argv[1] and array[0] won't work, but I can't figure out another clever way of comparing it. If i am correct, argv is an array of an array of pointers...Very weird .

EDIT;

I fixed the while loop with this,

```
array = (char *) malloc(15);
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    array[i]=c;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to find "paul" in each line of the file, or in the whole file?

Comment: Well, my beatles.txt only has one line and it's paul, and using the emthod ./a.out paul < beatles.txt, I hope that the word paul is passed to argv and then the word paul in beatles.txt is read by my w hile loop and stored in an array. Than I will compare argv with the array and if both strings are same then i print true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code I've edited for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Edit (0) - added helper variable
    int i = 0, c = 0;

    // Edit (1) - replaced with array of chars with fixed size 
    char array[32] = {0};

    char *chant;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        // Edit(2)
        array[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    // Edit (3) - you need to use here two arrays (not single char) terminated by '\0' 
    chant = strstr(argv[1], array);
    if (chant == NULL)
        printf("false\n");
    else
        printf("true\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, argv[] is an array of C-strings. Therefore, argv[1] returns the second string passed as an argument to your program, which is "paul" in your case.

array[0] on the other hand returns an int. The reason why your code is not compiling is because you are passing an argument of type int (array[0]) in a function that takes char pointers.

Other than that, there are a couple of mistakes in your code that will cause problems.

First off, you are trying to access a non-initialized array :

```
int *array;
array[0]=c;
```

Also, you are inserting a char inside an array of integers, which is probably not what you want.

One last thing to note :

```
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    array[0]=c;

}
```

These lines of code continuously overwrite the value located at array[0], this is not the correct way for building a c-string.

I suggest you read a bit more on c-style strings.
A good reference would be the string.h library, which contains multiple functions on string manipulation : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this, I hope it solves my problem of comparing argv with array.